# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: xcode, swift

Ребята подскажите в чем ошибка? уже все два контроллера пролистал, все переходы, кнопки или лейблы не правильно соединенные.Уже заново удалял и вставлял.Когда уже ViewController подсоединяешь класс и UITableViewCell. Начинает выбивать эту ошибку.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "b9Q-pS-svG-view-UNB-uH-ALi" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097b71cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ac96f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010982bb95 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010b9980f5 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 527
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b69a941 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b69b19e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b708fcc -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 466
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b70834f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b70433c -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 410
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b70410b -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 109
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b7081f4 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 384
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b4fe9bd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b990cac -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 597
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b4fe9bd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b675183 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b6754a0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b9936b2 -[UITabBar _buttonUp:] + 113
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b4fe9bd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010b675183 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010b6754a0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b6743cd -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b572d4f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b574472 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b519802 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010be4ba50 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010be4e5b7 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010975a2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097f9d31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010973ec19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010973e1ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010973da89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011187d9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010b4fcd30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    33  BRAVOBET                            0x000000010876df67 main + 55
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010eb42d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) 

import UIKit
import Parse

class RecalTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var comment = [Comment]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return comment.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!RacalTableViewCell

        cell.comment.text = comment[indexPath.row].comment
        cell.nameAndCounry.text = comment[indexPath.row].nameAndCounry
        // Configure the cell...
        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MMM.yyyy"
        cell.comment.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date as  Date)
        return cell
    }




}
```

Comment: Можете привести код ViewController'а?

Comment: Да,  щас добавлю

Comment: В вашем сториборде экран типа `UITableViewController` ?

Comment: да, я   ее искал нет такой.

Comment: Проверьте, является ли ваш экран TableViewController'ом. Возможно, у вас он представлен как обычный ViewController + таблица (потому как `but didn't get a UITableView` - в nib файле не найдена вьюшка типа UITableView). Если же все верно, попробуйте отчистить Derived Data и удалить приложение с устройства и собрать все заново

Comment: Я уже убирал и все равно требует.Это обратно рассоеденить все контроллере и заново собрать?

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики. Что убирали, с каким контроллером какого типа на сториборде ассоциирован `RecalTableViewController`. Как отчистить Derived Date можете прочесть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/2350792

Comment: Да,  я эту статью сам нашел и читал.Да я все равно потом xib tableviewcell добавляю.Все проблема решена.Поставь Ответ, сделаю галочку зеленую.